# I want To Add Story(Comment) With Created By Field Asana Api

Tags: c#, asana-api

Hello I Want to Change Created_by Filed Value While Adding Comment In Task in Asana API

Here is my code

```
var jsonObject = "{\"data\" : {\"text\" : \"" + comments[i].Comment + "\",\"created_by\": [{\"id\": \"" + userDetail.id + "\", \"name\": \"" + userDetail.name + "\" }]}}";
```

Above Is my Json Object That I am passing While calling API

```
UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder("https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks/" + TaskId + "/stories");**
```

Here above is my API that I am calling to add story

```
{"errors":[{"message":"created_by: Cannot write this property","help":"For more information on API status codes and how to handle them, read the docs on errors: https://asana.com/developers/documentation/getting-started/errors"}]}
```

here is the response that I am getting

can someone help me to find out created_by filed value

Comment: I'm assuming the created_by property is handled by the Asana API itself, based on the current user, and that it is not a custom field? The error itself indicates that the API doesn't allow it, and handles that field itself. perhaps just use a custom field to keep track of the creator?

Comment: So There Is No Way To change Created_by Filed?

Comment: I haven't found anything about it in the documentation, but the error code seems to be a custom one by Asana Api itself. So i think they're protecting this field for a reason. probably best to just use a custom field.